# SQL Error 1005: Can't create table

Tags: mysql

Estoy usando workbench en modo grafico, hice un modelo y ahora me da el siguiente error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `bd_easymaker_0`.`herramientas` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update")
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Herramientas`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Herramientas` (
          `ID_Herramienta` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `ID_Dueño` INT NOT NULL,
          `Descripcion` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
          `Desc_Estado` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          `Ubicacion` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
          `Prerequisitos` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `ID_Imagen` INT NOT NULL,
          `HoC` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
          `Duracion` INT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Herramienta`),
          INDEX `ID_Dueño_idx` (`ID_Dueño` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Imagen_idx` (`ID_Imagen` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_ID_Dueño`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Dueño`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `FK_ID_Imagen`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Imagen`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Imagenes` (`ID_Imagen`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Soy novato en BD espero me puedan ayudar, creo que es un error de diseño.

Comment: Esto normalmente se debe porque tienes otro constraint en alguna otra tabla que se llama igual a alguna de las dos que tienes aquí. Busca en tus demás tablas si no tendrás un constraint llamado ``FK_ID_Dueño`` ó ``FK_ID_Imagen``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en el CONSTRAINT FK_ID_IMAGEN, debes renombrarlo:

```
-- Table `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Herramientas`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Herramientas` (
          `ID_Herramienta` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `ID_Dueño` INT NOT NULL,
          `Descripcion` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
          `Desc_Estado` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
          `Ubicacion` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
          `Prerequisitos` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
          `ID_Imagen` INT NOT NULL,
          `HoC` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
          `Duracion` INT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Herramienta`),
          INDEX `ID_Dueño_idx` (`ID_Dueño` ASC),
          INDEX `ID_Imagen_idx` (`ID_Imagen` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_ID_Dueño`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Dueño`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Usuarios` (`ID_Usuario`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `FK_ID_Imagen_Herram`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Imagen`)
            REFERENCES `BD_EasyMaker_0`.`Imagenes` (`ID_Imagen`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Esto se debe a que en tu tabla "Equipos" ya tienes un CONSTRAINT llamando FK_ID_IMAGEN

Comment: ¿Cómo lo sabes que ese es el error?

Comment: Ya había hecho una pregunta anterior a esta, y tenía un error similar, creó una tabla en la que declaró un constraint con el nombre FK_ID_Imagen por eso tiene el error. Perdón por no aclarar esto

Comment: Ohhh, ok, ahora entiendo.